# Design of a Communication Stack on CAN

Tags: c, embedded, communication, scheduler, network-protocols

My Goal is to design and implement a portable Communication Stack on CAN.
To be simple let's assume that the protocol stack i want implement is composed of the following Layers :

1) Data Link Layer : CAN driver and so on

2) Communication Layer: Handle the filtering of the frame in reception and Manage the sending of periodic / Event triggered frames

3) Transport Layer :Manage the segmentation of messages (Standard CAN protocol only allows a frames with length of 8 Byte)

4) Application Layer : defined by the end user

[image: Communication Stack]

The choice of my design is to build the comunication stack around a non preemptif scheduler and to consider each layer as a task of the scheduler the communication between the different layers is done using communication mechanisms mutex and queues ext.
The questions are:

1) Could this be a good design or there is much easier one

2) How do the Communication stacks really work? , I mean what is the "engine" behind the application layer, Is it a scheduler? or the management of the communication between layers is defined by the end user?

3) Could anyone point me to a free and easy implementation (Ideally in c)  of a communication stack (Not necessary for CAN)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using an existing protocol on top of CAN. This could be [CANopen](http://www.can-cia.org/can-knowledge/canopen/canopen/). A free implementation is [CAN Festival](http://www.canfestival.org/)

Comment: Thank you @Harper, i will take a look

Answer (score 0):

> Transport Layer :Manage the segmentation of messages

No, this is the application layer. It doesn't make sense to handle segmentation unless you have a high-level protocol specifying which CAN identifiers to use and the nature of the data.

The application layer in this case needs to be implemented by you and not the end user. Otherwise you are not making a protocol stack, but merely some glorified CAN driver. Which identifiers are there? The nature of the data? Priorities? How are messages scheduled on the bus over time? Is the system sending data repeatedly and synchronously, or is it event-driven? Are RTR frames used and how? And so on.

> How do the Communication stacks really work? , I mean what is the "engine" behind the application layer, Is it a scheduler? or the management of the communication between layers is defined by the end user?

This is quite a broad question, but generally such stacks are event-driven. There a message pump directing incoming data to whoever needs it. The CAN stack need to implement some sort of hardware timer for a given hardware port, to keep track of message timing, but possibly also to keep track of itself.

Some stacks have the possibility to take a "time slice" as parameter and then schedule themselves in a way. Others are built on the concept of doing as little as possible each time they are called, but instead count on constantly getting called repeatedly from the main loop. Whichever makes most sense depends on the end application, really. The former concept might make most sense in applications with RTOS or low power applications. The latter makes most sense for high integrity, fast response systems, like for example a car ECU.

> 3) Could anyone point me to a free and easy implementation (Ideally in c) of a communication stack (Not necessary for CAN)

(Please note that asking for external resources like libraries is off-topic on SO.)

http://www.canfestival.org is a free CANopen stack. I haven't used it myself, so I have no idea of the quality.

Comment: Thank You Lundin for the Answers, i should have have put you in the context in the begining the stack i want design is for automotive ECU (fast response system). for the 1st point, i don't share your opinion here, Transport layer should deal with the segmentation, in fact we have to configure the communication layer in a way when the stack received the ID of a segmented message it calls the Transport Layer. The application layer mainly decide what to do with the received frame, and maybe call other modules (this depend on your global system)

Comment: 2nd Point, the stack am going to design will take time from the main loop (for example called every 10ms), what i want to know is do you agree with the design i have made a scheduler with several task (task = layer of comm stack), knowing that the stack have to deal with sending / receiving periodic frames ext...(lot of job). I know it's a broad question, but i want someone who light me the way to start.

Comment: @fedi The thing is, you have to design the protocol around CAN frames and their priorities. They dictate the bus load. You want both the system and the CAN bus traffic to be deterministic. Arbitrary package lengths etc are not going to work in an automotive system, unless you are designing some pre-operational/configuration mode etc (like CANopen SDOs). Anyway, it all depends on the system requirements.